# how to load the images from cloud server like Microsoft Azure Cloud server

Tags: graphics, cloud

Is any option available to load the images from cloud server like Microsoft Azure Cloud server
through the `\graphicspath{}` path section like
`\graphicspath{ {https://iwmsdmsps.azurewebsites.net/OpenKM/rest-service/api/downloaddocument/} }`

Comment: As a rule LaTeX cannot go online to get stuff. It would also be super annoying to keep downloading the image each time you compile. Thus is it always better to keep the images on local disk (or in your overleaf project).

Comment: Actually it can through shell-escape. About the annoying part, it depends on how fast your network connection is; however it's definitely easier to just have some program in other programming language to do the downloading part.